# Selecting an Android emulator for running a react-native app

Tags: android, react-native

I need to run my application on different device in order to take screenshots and publish on the Google play store.Not owning all the different types requested, I went down the rabbit hole of trying to run my app on different emulators.

Adding the various type in SDK was straight forward. But selecting the correct one to run was the difficulty (except if running inside the Android Studio GUI, which I prefer not).

After talking to chatGPT and spending lots of time I finally found that this command:
`npx react-native run-android --list-devices`
allows me to select which emualator to use. Cool!!

But for day to day development I need the development environment.

`npx react-native start`, which is used to start the environment AND also start an emulator if none is running does not support `--list-devices`; it just picks up something. Which one and based on what criteria? I don't know.

So, here is my question:

- How to select which emulator to start when starting the development environment
- How to set a default emulator